# Dynamic Image in Content Builder using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I have 1 000 images stored in a file, in Content Builder. 
Each image corresponds with a user. 
Image names are the users' id.

When an email is sent to a given user, I want his photo to be displayed in the email.

I would like to know if an ampscript function allows me to display the image whose name matches with my user's id.

I found the functions ContentImageById and ContentImageByKey but what I would like to use is the image name, not the ID or the key.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

**Option 1:**
I understand that you have a lot of images, and the option 2 is not very suitable for your use case.

You can use the "Predictable File URLs" fonctionnality on your account. You can enable it by going to Setup > Platform Tools > Content Builder > Content Builder Settings

Since the image names are your users ids, each image would have a unique id. This way, you can predict your images urls and call them directly on your email using something similar to:

```
<img src="CONCAT('https://yourdomain.com/lib/',CONCAT(@SubscriberKey,'.png/jpeg/..'))"/>
```

> By default, Content Builder generates a unique identifier for the
>   uploaded file's name. Predictable URLs use the uploaded file name as
>   the end of the URL path for the published file. This feature applies
>   only to files uploaded after enablement. Upload files with unique
>   filenames. Filenames can include alphanumeric characters, hyphens,
>   underscores, and periods.

**Option 2:**
You can use the `ContentBlockByName` function.

> Returns content contained in the specified stored content block or
>   code snippet from Content Builder, including the Image Block type.

Example:

```
%%=ContentBlockByName("Content Builder\Weekly Portfolio")=%%
```

You can use it with `CONCAT('Content Builder\', _SubscriberKey)` to automate the selection of the image..

Keep in mind that this function will only work with an Image block and not with a simple Image:

**Image type:**
[image]

**Image block type:**

[image]

To create an image block, go to Content Builder > Create > Content Blocks > Image Block

Check out the documentation here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyname.htm

Comment: Thanks Rachid ! I also tried thtis function but it looks like it is not working with Image Block, it only works with text / layout blocks...

Comment: Try using ampscript image functions like `ContentImageByKey()`. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentimagebykey.htm. For this you would have to use the contactkey rather than the name.

Comment: @Clothilde, I think that you are testing with an Image and not an Image Block. Check out my answer, I've updated it to explain the difference..

Comment: @RachidMamai the thing is I have 1700 photos, is there a way to easily create these 1700 Image Blocks ?

Comment: @Clothilde, I've updated my answer accordingly. Check out the first option and tell me if it suits your needs

Comment: @RachidMamai your first option is perfect for my case ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Clothilde perfect, glad I can help. Don't forget to accept the answer to help other identify it.